# Searching database content : laravel

Tags: php

```
public function scopeSearchByKeyword($query, $keyword)
{
    if ($keyword!='') {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where("name", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("email", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("blood_group", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("phone", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

What is '$query' parameter used for? Also what does function($query) use ($keyword){} mean?

```
$keyword = Input::get('keyword', '');
$users = User::SearchByKeyword($keyword)->get();
```

Why is it only 'SearchByKeyword' and not scopeSearchByKeyword?

Comment: Did you even bother reading the Laravel docs?

Comment: yeah... Went through some of sections.... can you help me out here?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes